# Integrating with PingFederate and PHP

Tags: pingfederate

We have a client that uses PingFederate for SSO.

We would like to integrate with them, and have been reading the Agentless integration documentation.

Is there anything we need to purchase from Ping Federate (any of their servers) for integrating with our client or is this something we can achieve by making RESTful calls to authenticate users coming from our client?

Answer (score 2):

So you cannot license an Integration Kit w/out the PingFederate server. However, you might want to check out the [PingOne APS](https://www.pingone.com/#developer) service from Ping. This will give you a REST API integration and no software to install. Plus, it will set you up to support SAML 1.1/2.0 for your other customers as well with the single integration [note: I work for Ping]

HTH
Ian

Comment: Hello Ian, I just wanted to clarify. Our client has active directory and they have PingFederate installed and using it to enable SSO on Yammer. We want to come in and offer our service through SSO. If we want them to be automatically logged in on our website, do we need to use PingFederate as well so there is no need to log in? If we use PingOne, they would still have to log in and we would use PingOne to communicate with their AD/PF to verify the credentials, correct?

Comment: So from your perspective, you would need some kind of SAML 2.0 SP capability built into your application to integrate with your customer's SAML 2.0 IDP (in this case PingFederate). IMHO PingOne APS is easiest way to enable your application for SAML 2.0. You would not need to "integrate" with PingFederate per se since PingFederate is simply generating SAML 2.0 Responses that you would need to validate/consume. You can contact me directly if you'd like to discuss in more detail. ibarnett AT pingidentity DOT com.